# How to recognize where the application crashes?

Tags: iphone, crash-log

```
Incident Identifier: 48A73A33-A035-4B2D-8CBB-AD513D96A9B3
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         Locally [599]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/8EF9B7A1-234A-4C26-BDF0-D22D45D0F8E8/Locally.app/Locally
Identifier:      Locally
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-05-08 00:00:22.722 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.2 (8H7)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32f75c98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Locally                         0x0001113a -[FlipsideInfoView valuesChanged:] + 46
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32a2856a -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:]
3   UIKit                           0x318b2ec2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
4   UIKit                           0x318b2e62 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:]
5   UIKit                           0x318b2e34 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
6   UIKit                           0x318b2b86 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
7   UIKit                           0x318ecbd2 -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:]
8   UIKit                           0x318ec81e -[UISegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:]
9   Locally                         0x000111da -[FlipsideInfoView valuesChanged:] + 206
10  CoreFoundation                  0x32a2856a -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:]
11  UIKit                           0x318b2ec2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
12  UIKit                           0x318b2e62 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:]
13  UIKit                           0x318b2e34 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
14  UIKit                           0x318b2b86 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
15  UIKit                           0x318ecbd2 -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:]
16  UIKit                           0x318ec81e -[UISegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:]
17  UIKit                           0x3193f3b0 -[UISegmentedControl(DeprecatedMethods) setSelectedSegment:]
18  UIKit                           0x3193f39c -[UISegmentedControl(DeprecatedMethods) selectSegment:]
19  UIKit                           0x3193f26a -[UISegmentedControl touchesBegan:withEvent:]
20  UIKit                           0x318b1baa -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
21  UIKit                           0x318b1568 -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
22  UIKit                           0x3189a30c -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
23  UIKit                           0x31899c4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent
24  GraphicsServices                0x31fa5e70 PurpleEventCallback
25  CoreFoundation                  0x32a8fa90 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
26  CoreFoundation                  0x32a91838 __CFRunLoopDoSource1
27  CoreFoundation                  0x32a92606 __CFRunLoopRun
28  CoreFoundation                  0x32a22ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
29  CoreFoundation                  0x32a22dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode
30  GraphicsServices                0x31fa5418 GSEventRunModal
31  GraphicsServices                0x31fa54c4 GSEventRun
32  UIKit                           0x318c4d62 -[UIApplication _run]
33  UIKit                           0x318c2800 UIApplicationMain
34  Locally                         0x00002a1a main + 42
35  Locally                         0x000029e4 start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3573d3ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369436d8 _pthread_wqthread
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36943bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3573dfbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x32dab032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x32dac03a _dispatch_queue_invoke
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x32dab5ea _dispatch_worker_thread2
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3694358a _pthread_wqthread
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36943bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3573ac00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3573a758 mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32a902b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32a92562 __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32a22ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32a22dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode
6   WebCore                         0x35dd827e RunWebThread
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3694230a _pthread_start
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36943bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3573ac00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3573a758 mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32a902b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32a92562 __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32a22ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32a22dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode
6   Foundation                      0x30e167f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:]
7   Foundation                      0x30e09382 -[NSThread main]
8   Foundation                      0x30e7b5c6 __NSThread__main__
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3694230a _pthread_start
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36943bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3573ac00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3573a758 mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32a902b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32a92562 __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32a22ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32a22dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode
6   MapKit                          0x32dbf456 TileCachePrivate::runCacheThread()
7   MapKit                          0x32dbf33a _runCacheThread(void*)
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3694230a _pthread_start
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36943bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3573cc60 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x32a958f2 __CFSocketManager
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3694230a _pthread_start
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36943bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 7 name:  CADispatch worker
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3573cd18 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36969860 _pthread_cond_wait
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36910eb2 pthread_cond_wait
3   QuartzCore                      0x34b9a730 CA::DispatchGroup::thread(void*)
4   QuartzCore                      0x34bb4836 thread_fun
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3694230a _pthread_start
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36943bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3573d3ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x369436d8 _pthread_wqthread
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36943bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x0014e130    r1: 0x32e5b76c      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00007ffe
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x001f5ea0      r6: 0x001f6cf0      r7: 0x2fdfe164
    r8: 0x0004bf88    r9: 0x00c3c208     r10: 0x001f6cf0     r11: 0x001f6cf0
    ip: 0x00011dd1    sp: 0x2fdfe104      lr: 0x00011141      pc: 0x32f75c98
  cpsr: 0x20080030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x5efff +Locally armv7  <6c1870d1fe74777d2cd85acf00a29cfd> /var/mobile/Applications/8EF9B7A1-234A-4C26-BDF0-D22D45D0F8E8/Locally.app/Locally
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30b25000 - 0x30b49fff  MediaControl armv7  <1cfc7d79f554357ab59eb69f9efebf07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControl.framework/MediaControl
0x30bf1000 - 0x30c4afff  EventKit armv7  <0d4e597ee229337183e96e921a72e30a> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x30c4e000 - 0x30c53fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x30c54000 - 0x30c56fff  MailServices armv7  <74ae0145ef713c6d91fd8f68885b0a61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x30c57000 - 0x30c5dfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x30c86000 - 0x30c87fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x30c88000 - 0x30cd9fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x30cda000 - 0x30d64fff  Message armv7  <25232d2097433678b1faf7deabdc368e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x30d91000 - 0x30d9efff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x30d9f000 - 0x30da9fff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30dec000 - 0x30f0bfff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x30f5b000 - 0x30f5efff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x3105f000 - 0x31072fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x31073000 - 0x31079fff  IAP armv7  <c0f4c99a1b493e489948f231ad9238e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x3107a000 - 0x31099fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x310a3000 - 0x310a6fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x310a7000 - 0x310dffff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31102000 - 0x31256fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x31257000 - 0x31264fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <d454cde062983860a41694922eb5c042> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x312c5000 - 0x312fcfff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x316e6000 - 0x31807fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3180b000 - 0x31852fff  MessageUI armv7  <35a81f5d4eb03467a1447db80337e570> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x31853000 - 0x31895fff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31896000 - 0x31c23fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x31c24000 - 0x31c29fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x31c32000 - 0x31c52fff  AppleAccount armv7  <4e0ac5cf93b338ab8c5f34ba3c5e2ee4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x31cda000 - 0x31cdcfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x31cdd000 - 0x31d15fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x31d18000 - 0x31d1cfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x31d1d000 - 0x31e0afff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x31e0b000 - 0x31f13fff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x31f14000 - 0x31f69fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x31fa1000 - 0x31fadfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <b5a7e43e0cd630739f56c4649b90c874> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3228d000 - 0x323a7fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x323a8000 - 0x323adfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x323b4000 - 0x324b8fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x324ba000 - 0x324f7fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3252e000 - 0x3253efff  WebBookmarks armv7  <6956561235333e74b8ff316cb2edc93e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x325b6000 - 0x325bcfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x32616000 - 0x32636fff  MobileSync armv7  <4df400c4559435889eccd88db77a110c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x326b9000 - 0x32728fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x32729000 - 0x3276ffff  CoreTelephony armv7  <bc7470708aa231fc8e24133b90f9ec32> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32770000 - 0x32780fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x327bc000 - 0x327bcfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x327bd000 - 0x327d3fff  EAP8021X armv7  <9659fa6b559835c39aa9134646bc75e9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3284b000 - 0x32850fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x32875000 - 0x3291efff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x32930000 - 0x3293efff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32954000 - 0x32956fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <fcadc63caa80335b8b35602a8deeab61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x329b9000 - 0x329e2fff  ContentIndex armv7  <ecd71782cd833360872b943ecc65d203> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x329e3000 - 0x329e7fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x329fc000 - 0x329fffff  ArtworkCache armv7  <4863e321afee3ac5a3749e50cd926597> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x32a17000 - 0x32a18fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x32a19000 - 0x32a19fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x32a1a000 - 0x32afffff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x32b20000 - 0x32b24fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x32b25000 - 0x32c37fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <da848c0745a637af81d7edd962a09324> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x32c40000 - 0x32c59fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32c67000 - 0x32c76fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <563a09bcdb2f32369b1e22f53f58273a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x32c99000 - 0x32d2efff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x32d2f000 - 0x32d6ffff  CoreMedia armv7  <0c181789446434eabf4eeed874ec211d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x32d70000 - 0x32da3fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x32da4000 - 0x32da4fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x32da5000 - 0x32db2fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x32db7000 - 0x32e73fff  MapKit armv7  <2755d38ec8683a07a86aa53826999e1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x32e77000 - 0x32f28fff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x32f29000 - 0x32f30fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x32f3b000 - 0x32f6efff  QuickLook armv7  <29d2d981d1d6358381f5716ee37314b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x32f73000 - 0x33037fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34a94000 - 0x34ad3fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x34b18000 - 0x34bc7fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x34bd9000 - 0x34bebfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <b1de729a101f32dcba0ad98161fb80b5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34cf3000 - 0x34cfffff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x34d00000 - 0x34dc1fff  RawCamera armv7  <0c52d8b1498c3dbb9aad95f3bcd8261d> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x34df7000 - 0x34e56fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x34f75000 - 0x35012fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x35126000 - 0x3513bfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3513c000 - 0x351e2fff  Celestial armv7  <db412e659f163c20a2e508b9f84b1d2d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x351e3000 - 0x3522bfff  CoreLocation armv7  <a13a050b1a9f313bb25c82c463e1dd8b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x3522c000 - 0x35235fff  ITSync armv7  <bda1710c8682358d8bf6eab660f41fdc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x35241000 - 0x35242fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x35247000 - 0x35249fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x35252000 - 0x35295fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <8a04bd2ef60e39ac8ea09f8f23232e94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x352e0000 - 0x355cdfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x356cc000 - 0x356fafff  DataAccess armv7  <3a2e67aa1d8834b7a8fc2fbb56654b15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x356fb000 - 0x3572afff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3572b000 - 0x35742fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x35758000 - 0x35775fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x35896000 - 0x35899fff  ActorKit armv7  <f7aa6cdd654231988aafcf448978f450> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x3589d000 - 0x3589efff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3589f000 - 0x358a4fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x35a07000 - 0x35a55fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x35ac7000 - 0x35ad0fff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x35ad1000 - 0x35b04fff  iCalendar armv7  <34ce1957082f3518b5740ac33cfc92eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x35b1c000 - 0x35b6afff  CoreMotion armv7  <8660c1394c5c39089407c07fd7fd8b52> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x35b75000 - 0x35c3bfff  MusicLibrary armv7  <e6b67de14a173197a07b61fdad63fdfb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x35c5a000 - 0x35c8dfff  StoreServices armv7  <d526715648f435c3aac4c42953e76d20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x35c8e000 - 0x35c96fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x35cd8000 - 0x35cd9fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x35dd2000 - 0x363ddfff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x363f0000 - 0x363fbfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x36401000 - 0x36401fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x36411000 - 0x36411fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x364cc000 - 0x36618fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <482b13059e8a329fa5d832baede25103> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x36620000 - 0x36623fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3663f000 - 0x36641fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x36657000 - 0x36685fff  MIME armv7  <60de1fe0bbb134d788c09f7c34b1caa4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x36686000 - 0x36687fff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x36763000 - 0x3678cfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3678d000 - 0x367adfff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x367ae000 - 0x367b5fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x368f1000 - 0x368fdfff  HomeSharing armv7  <2df6957cdfea31aea12eebf27ca1691c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x3690f000 - 0x36990fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3699e000 - 0x369e8fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x369e9000 - 0x369f7fff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <e54fa5bf6f9333618401cdbaf665f227> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x36a19000 - 0x36a20fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x36add000 - 0x36b11fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <570c63dc3a273a5a8c9072fd5567f5c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x36b1f000 - 0x36bdefff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36c76000 - 0x36c7ffff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x36c80000 - 0x36c83fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x36c84000 - 0x36c93fff  Notes armv7  <d9c976ca976e3d029f69febd48f17601> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x36c94000 - 0x36cc9fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x36cf3000 - 0x36cf5fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x36d90000 - 0x36dccfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x36ed2000 - 0x36ed5fff  CertUI armv7  <9060fe03a4943ef295531feced9a17dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x36edb000 - 0x371eefff  GeoServices armv7  <88616f3deada3bb495fc15e3ba58dc83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x371ef000 - 0x371f2fff  MediaRemote armv7  <0804293b2774359189f3a67e2c81558d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the crash log's stack trace, the last method from you that was run in `-[FlipsideInfoView valuesChanged:]`. The `+ 46` means 46 bytes into the method's binary.

The crash itself is with `obj_msgSend` which means it crashed while trying to call a method on an object.

```
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000008
```

Combined with this message the most likely reason is that you've got a method call, say `[myVar someMethod];`, in which the value of `myVar` isn't a valid pointer but simply "8".

So you need to analyze your `-[FlipsideInfoView valuesChanged:]` method and think about how one of your object pointers could go bust.

Of course, the very best way to analyze this to reproduce it when attached to the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly open your XCode
->Go to Run
->Select Stop on Objective-c Exception.

You can see the stack trace for the crashes as well.You can see the crash line below the threads coloum and the line of crash would be in black color.
Moreover
Now you need to put the breakpoints in your app that is also the best way.
And debug step by step.
Well by using  Stop on Objective-c Exception. your app will stop on the exception and will
show you the line below thread part when you open your debugger.

Well by seeing your code I found that your app is crashing due to early release of the object as its showing EXC_BAD_ACCESS message.

Hope this will help you....
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the line that might be what has caused the problem.

```
8   UIKit   0x318ec81e -[UISegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:]
```

or the method that you are calling when segmented controller value changes.